# Running multiple R scripts using the system() command

Tags: r, parallel-processing, system

I'm running RStudio in Windows 7. I have written a master script that generates 57 new R scripts, each with commands to run a function based on two parameters:

```
vector1 <- c(1:19)
vector2 <- c(1:3)
```

First, the master script uses two for-loops (one using the index 'abc' for *vector1*, one using the index 'def' for *vector2*) to generate each of the 57 scripts in my working directory that take the following filename convention:

```
run_inference_<<vector1[abc]>>_<<vector2[def]>>.R
```

That part runs successfully - each of the 57 scripts is generated with the correct commands inside. My working directory now contains files *run_inference_1_1.R*, *run_inference_1_2.R*, etc.

The final thing I want to do is then run all 57 scripts from my master, and simultaneously. I've tried the following inside the for-loop:

```
system(paste0("Rscript run_inference_",abc, "_", def, ".R"),wait = F)
```

This does not work. However, if I open one of the 57 generated scripts and run it then I get the desired result from that script. This tells me the issue is within the system() command that I've written.

Each of the 57 scripts will not be computationally intensive (yet), and the test I want to do now should take 2 minutes on my PC. How can I edit my system() command to execute all 57 scripts simultaneously, please?

Comment: `sapply(paste0("Rscript run_inference_",abc, "_", def, ".R"), system, wait = F)` No comment on whether if generating and running 57 script is a good idea or not for your problem.

Comment: I do echo Vlo's unspoken concern that there is probably a better way to do this. Why do you want to write out the scripts instead of doing something like having a function that takes the required input and just running that function with the 57 different inputs you desire?

Comment: I have a well-resourced PC that should be able to handle very intensive jobs, and colleagues more familiar with parallel computing have told me this task should be doable given what's available. We shall see!

Answer (score 5):

You don't do this by calling `system` once with a big script, unless the program you're running knows how to parallelise the script itself. You do this by calling `system` multiple times from different R processes.

```
scripts <- paste0("Rscript run_inference_", abc, "_", def, ".R")

# make lots of R processes, assuming the script to be called won't eat CPU
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(30)

parallel::parLapply(cl, scripts, function(script) system(script))
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll experiment with this and see how it goes.

Running big jobs like this is new to me, so this is a great 'baptism of fire', as it were.