# Running system() inside foreach()

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, system

I am running R version 3.4.1 on Windows 7.

I need to run a certain program using N=500 bootstrapped data files that I have stored within a working directory. The executable will produce 3 more datafiles for each of the N runs, all of which are stored in one working directory. I'd like to use parallel computing to increase the speed of this process.

The loop requires one starting file ('starter') that gets modified at every iteration of the loop. This is a really important part that I can't really get around doing. Also, at every iteration any pre-existing data files are removed and then the executable is called using system(). The executable produces the three data files called Report, CompReport, and covar.

In a normal loop the process looks something like this:

```
starter_strt <- SS_readstarter(file="starter.ss") # read starter file
    for(iboot in 1:N){
     starter$datfile <- paste("BootData", iboot, ".ss", sep="")

     #code to replace the starter file with the new one
     SS_writestarter(starter, overwrite=TRUE)

     #any old files are removed
     file.remove("Report.sso", paste("Report_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))
     file.remove("CompReport.sso", paste("CompReport_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))
     file.remove("covar.sso", paste("covar_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))

     #then the program is called
      system("ss3")
     #the files produced get pushed to the working directory
     file.copy("Report.sso",paste("Report_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))
     file.copy("CompReport.sso",paste("CompReport_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))
     file.copy("covar.sso",paste("covar_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))
    }
```

This above process takes 5 days to complete so I've been exploring options for parallelization. What I've worked with so far doesn't work so any help or suggestions are appreciated. Here's what I was thinking. Using a foreach loop and making sure I'm not reading and overwriting the starter file. This is what I have:

```
# read starter file

starter_strt <- SS_readstarter(file="starter.ss") # read starter file
iter <- 2 #just for an example here even though I said N=500 above
cores <-  parallel::detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterCall(cl, function(x) .libPaths(x), .libPaths())   

foreach(iboot=1:iter, .packages='r4ss', .export="starter_strt", system          ("ss3")) %dopar% {

  #code to create the starter file so I don't overwrite it 
  datfile<- data.frame(rep(paste("BootData",iboot,".ss",sep=""),2))
  colnames(datfile) <- "datfile"
  starter_list <- cbind(starter_strt, datfile)

  # replace starter file with modified version
  SS_writestarter(starter_list, overwrite=TRUE)

  #delete files as above
  #run program
   system("ss3")
 #the files produced get pushed to the working directory
 file.copy("Report.sso",paste("Report_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))
 file.copy("CompReport.sso",paste("CompReport_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))
 file.copy("covar.sso",paste("covar_",iboot,".sso",sep=""))

}
```

The program runs through once but then I get a warning (see below) and the expected files are missing from the directory.

```
Warning message:
In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
  already exporting variable(s): starter_strt
```

I'm pretty stumped at this point. I saw this example [Running multiple R scripts using the system() command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370537/running-multiple-r-scripts-using-the-system-command) where the system command is called in a parLapply function. Maybe this is what I need? Help and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: On a quick reading, it appears that each iteration of your loop depends on the previous iteration. If this is true, then you can't parallelize your outer loop. If there is no dependence, then maybe you can generate a list of the starter files and then feed that as part of your loop iteration.

Comment: Do you get the problem if it isn't run in parallel? If so, you can debug it using `options(error=recover)`.

Comment: @lmo Hum. I see what you mean. But is it really a dependent process if the starter file is just being adjusted based on the iterator? starter2 isn't dependent on starter1, it's just that starter2 doesn't get created until iteration 1 completes.

Comment: A warning is not an error, and doesn't stop R from continuing the loop.  Have you tried just removing "starter_strt" from `.export`?

Comment: @thc I have. Also, I was under the assumption that all of the workers need to have access to the referenced matrices so that's why I used .export  in the first place.

Comment: @Elizabeth it isn't clear what you are asking.  What you have written isn't an error, so what is the issue?  Also, did you know that you defined `iter <- 2`, although you wrote that you wanted to test 500 bootstraps?  Was that just for example?

Comment: @thc,  Right, it was just for an example. I know the process fails after the first go around because the expected files for round 2 are not within the working directory. I will update in my post for clarity.

Comment: It could be that the program is trying to use and modify starter.ss -- if multiple threads are doing that, it will fail.  You could try duplicating starter.ss to e.g., starter_<iter>.ss and defining it within the loop, instead of outside.

Comment: From what I understand from your code, every parallel node will manipulate the same files at the same time, which is a problem.

Comment: @thc, Yes, I think that is what I'll have to do. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @F.Privé  Alas, it appears that way after all... Thanks for your thought!

Comment: @Elizabeth You're command line function doesn't have an argument to specify the names of the files you manipulate?

Comment: @F.Privé  If you mean command line function as in system(ss3) then no, it doesn't because the program itself was written to expect 4 specific file names. Therefore, no need for specification.

Comment: @Elizabeth So, the only thing you can do is to make one directory for each parallel node, and make them work in their own directory.

Comment: @F.Privé Was just discussing this with a coworker and we agree this is our only option. Not what I was hoping for but at least it's not a user limitation, just inherent to the system.